# After Connection second display window manger/unity fail to start

Tags: unity, ati, 13.04, multiple-monitors, window-manager

I am running 13.04.  AMD RV710.  Dual 1900x1200.  I installed on a single display and when I added the new one I got a lot of oddities.  One is that one reboot sometimes I just don't get a window manager.  It sometimes crashes as well.

Been very happy up to this point but I am running VM's in virutalbox and this is a work machine so I might have to go another route if this doesn't get figured out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Same issue here; I'm having to unplug the second monitor when I reboot, and plug it back in once the desktop shows. Can't find a way to make the settings persist past a reboot.

Comment: (Btw: I'm running gnome-shell with the same issue, so the unity tag might be optional)

Comment: Is AMD RV710 an "hybrid" graphics card ?